# Count of rows in pyspark dataframe over a window

Tags: pyspark, count, sql-function

I have a pyspark dataframe with below data

[[image: The columns #, A, B and C is my data.]

My code:

```
W = Window.partitionBy("A").orderBy(col("C"))
main_df = main_df.withColumn("cnt", F.count("B").over(W))
```

Is there something wrong in how I have used the count function? What can I do so the values in column 'Actual' match with 'Expecting'?
I see two issues with my output -

1. the count starts at 1 when it should start from 0
2. for each group the last count is getting assigned instead of the first

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You did not specify the Window rowsBetween and so it will include the current row that is why it starts from 1. And if you want to get the same count for the duplicated value, use dense_rank function not the count function.

Comment: Thank you, I will try using rowsBetween and see if it helps not using  -1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `dense_rank` window function and `substract 1` from the `dense_rank` value.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('0','king','4/30/2022'),('1','king','5/17/2022'),('2','king','5/26/2022'),('3','king','6/5/2022'),('4','king','7/8/2022'),('5','king','7/9/2022'),('6','king','4/21/2023'),('7','king','4/21/2023'),('8','king','4/22/2023'),('9','king','8/22/2023')],['#','A','C'])
W = Window.partitionBy("A").orderBy(col("C"))

df.withColumn("c",to_date(col("C"),"M/dd/yyyy")).\
  withColumn("Expecting",dense_rank().over(W)-1).show()
#+---+----+----------+---------+
#|  #|   A|         c|Expecting|
#+---+----+----------+---------+
#|  0|king|2022-04-30|        0|
#|  1|king|2022-05-17|        1|
#|  2|king|2022-05-26|        2|
#|  3|king|2022-06-05|        3|
#|  4|king|2022-07-08|        4|
#|  5|king|2022-07-09|        5|
#|  6|king|2023-04-21|        6|
#|  7|king|2023-04-21|        6|
#|  8|king|2023-04-22|        7|
#|  9|king|2023-08-22|        8|
#+---+----+----------+---------+
```